# how to make a jquery plugin reusable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, click

I have this plugin issue for ages but can't get it right.

Here is the test [page](http://jsfiddle.net/uKyWJ/). When you click on the **page** button, it should alert `page` **twice**, but it alert `photo` at the **second** time.

It does that because I re-use that plugin for another button called 'photo'. I think the second button overwrite the first button in someway which I don't quite understand why it does.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.get-page').get_overlay({
        targetObject:         '.page'
    });

    $('.get-photo').get_overlay({
        targetObject:         '.photo'
    });

});
```

Then this means that this plugin cannot be reused at all then what is the point having a plugin in the first place?

Any idea where I have done wrong in this plugin? How can I fix it?

```
(function($){

    $.fn.get_overlay = function(options) {

             var defaults = {
                targetObject:            ''
            }

            var options =  $.extend(defaults, options);
            var o = options;

            var $cm = this.click(function() {

                alert(o.targetObject);

                $.fn.get_overlay.centralise();

                return false;



            });

            if(!$.fn.get_overlay.centralise) $.fn.get_overlay.centralise = {};

            $.fn.get_overlay.centralise = function() {

                alert(o.targetObject);

            }

    }      
})(jQuery);​
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**@lauthiamkok**, I think you need to revise the plugin authoring guide at jquery docs. It's probably not a good idea to do this `$.fn.get_overlay.centralise` inside you plugin. If you want to have access to `centralise()` from the public scope you should make it a method. Then, as the authoring guide advises, it's recommended to return the jquery object to allow chaining for your plugin.
Check working example at http://jsfiddle.net/elclanrs/FrMSY/1/

```
$.fn.get_overlay = function(options) {

    var o = $.extend({
        targetObject: ''
    }, options);
    var $this = this;

    $this.centralise = function() {
        alert(o.targetObject);
    };

    return this.each(function() {
        $(this).click(function() {
            alert(o.targetObject);
            $this.centralise();
            return false;
        });
    });

};
```

Comment: thanks for this answer, elclanrs. if I follow this format, how can I access the `centralise` from the public scope?

Comment: like this: `$el.get_overlay().centralise()`

Comment: Your way of reusing code helped me a lot developing my own plugin for pagination. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a local variable to store the `targetObject`, use [.data](http://api.jquery.com/data/) to store it.

Comment: @lauthiamkok Any reason not using it?

Comment: sorry error typing in my reply. I haven't used `data` before and don't know how to use it to get the information. had a read through on the jquery website but still don't know how to use it in my plugin. could you please give an example?  thanks.

Comment: thanks for the answer, xdazz! I am going to have a deep study on it! :-)